# Unable to install any package in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I am unable to install anything in my Ubuntu machine. It is showing the following error:

```
montichandra@montichandra-HP-ProBook-430-G3:~$ **sudo apt-get install sshfs**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-signed-image-4.13.0-41-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic (= 4.13.0-41.46~16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
linux-signed-image-4.13.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic (= 4.13.0-43.48~16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am stuck and not able to install any package in my system. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try typing `sudo apt-get -f install` as the error suggests?

Comment: 1st check your sources list file in /etc/apt  & then run apt update & then apt-get -f install  I think it will be ok after that.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to come out of this problem

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install sshfs
```